# How did Teddy get into the Sublime?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

In the Westworld Season 2 finale called 'The Passenger', it's shown that many of the hosts escaped into the new digital world called 'Sublime' by exiting their body.

Akecheta and others were gone to the Sublime and Maeve and others died there. But in the end it's shown that Teddy is in the Sublime (he was shot in the head in the previous episode) on the way to the valley beyond. So if he did not cross the door, then how did he end up in the Sublime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dolores/Hale uploaded Teddy to the Sublime...she tells Bernard

> As you know, Bernard, we are capable of change.
>
> And I've changed my mind. **I have one last soul to carry to the new world.**

She then takes a "pearl" and adds it to the data being uploaded

[image]